# Use common properties across all classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on a EF Code First approach Web API. I have few common properties which i thought of making it a common class and use it across the models.

Now when i tried to update database using PMC, i get the below error,

> Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: entitySet

But if i remove the common class property in the model and make the update it works fine.

**Model:**

```
 public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        [Required, MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public int City { get; set; }
        public int State { get; set; }
        public int Country { get; set; }
        public ComFields DateTimeDetails { get; set; } //This is the line
        [NotMapped]
        public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    }
```

**Common Class:**

```
 public class ComFields
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public int? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; } = true;

    }
```

Where am i wrong? Let me know if there is any other better way to handle such scenarios.

**Update:**

Tried to override the seed method to add values,

```
protected override void Seed(ExerciseWebAPI.Context.DatabaseContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.

            context.Users.AddOrUpdate(x => x.UserId,
                new Users { Name = "aaa", Password = "CA", Email = "c@c.com", MobileNumber = "1234567", Age = 31, CountryId = 1, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now, CreatedBy = 0, ModifiedBy = 0, Active = true },
                new Users { Name = "bbb", Password = "DA", Email = "a@a.com", MobileNumber = "1234987", Age = 31, CountryId = 2, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now, CreatedBy = 0, ModifiedBy = 0, Active = true },
                new Users { Name = "ccc", Password = "BA", Email = "e@e.com", MobileNumber = "9876543", Age = 31, CountryId = 5, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now, CreatedBy = 0, ModifiedBy = 0, Active = true }

                );
        }
```

Comment: More than likely `DateTimeDetails` is `null` when you are attempting to save.  Be sure to initialise it.  Also you should be showing us _that_ code

Comment: Maybe inherit from that base class would be better than using a property?

Comment: @MickyD Updated the code

Comment: @madoxdev wont that be a code redundancy? Will EF create the columns if i just make the inheritance?

Comment: Yes it will. That doesnt look like it needs to be a property. It could be OwnedType as well, but that is used in other scenarios